# Loading a collection with objects using bpy.data.libraries.load, to avoid using a bpy.ops operator

Tags: python, objects, collections, append

I want to append a collection and the objects within that collection from a blender file, using `bpy.data.libraries.load`. The reason to use `bpy.data.libraries.load` is to avoid using a `bpy.ops` operator, which will make the python script slow. If I load a collection from the blender file using the code below, the collection remains empty.

```
MainDir = bpy.path.abspath("//")
filename='Plants/Forbs collection.blend'    
    
with bpy.data.libraries.load(MainDir + filename) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.collections = [c for c in data_from.collections if c=="Woodland forbs"]

for new_coll in data_to.collections:
    instance = bpy.data.objects.new(new_coll.name, None)
    instance.instance_type = 'COLLECTION'
    instance.instance_collection = new_coll
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(instance)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I would also like to know an answer to that... I am appending (or even linking would be fine) lots of files, and this gets painfully slow!

Comment: ops.wm operators are know to become slow when the scene gets very big, because it checks the entire scene after each import (it seems). And it has been like this since version 2.7 or before. Use bpy.data.libraries.load alternatively.